# How to preserve spacing between array elements?

Tags: math-mode

I have this code

```
\[
[-0.5 0 -1.5]
\]
```

but I get this result:

[image]

I want to respect the spaces, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `array` or a TABstack.  With the latter, the intercolumn gap is specified by way of `\setstacktabbedgap{6pt}`.

You could also use a `\bracketMatrixstack{}` in lieu of `[\Matrixstack{}]`, which would invoke the `\left[...\right]` mechanism, in case the matrix grew to several rows in height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\setstacktabbedgap{6pt}
\begin{document}
\[
[\begin{array}{@{}ccc@{}}
-0.5 & 0 &-1.5
\end{array}]
\]
\[
[\Matrixstack{-0.5 & 0 &-1.5}]
\]
\[
\bracketMatrixstack[r]{-0.5 & .0 &-1.5\\ 11.0 & 2.0 & 3.0}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Or you can simply use `\[[0.5\,0\,0.5]\]`. That will provide space between numbers.